# How to let regex know that it should stop after a first occurence?

Tags: c#, regex

```
string time = "Job started: donderdag 6 mei 2010 at 20:00:02"
var filterReg = new Regex(@".*:", RegexOptions.Compiled);
time = filterReg.Replace(time, String.Empty);
```

Is it possible to stop after the first occurence? so at the first ":".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason you're using regular expressions to get a simple substring?

```
time = time.Substring(time.IndexOf(":") + 1);
```

Comment: Sometimes the simple tool is better than the complicated one.

Answer (score 2):

By using a more specific regex

```
new Regex(@"^[^:]*:", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Your `.*:` does this

1. `.*` matches everything, greedily, so it runs right to the end of the string.
2. `:` tries to match, so the regex engine goes back one character at a time (this is called backtracking) to find a match. It stops at the first colon it finds (seen from the end of the string)

whereas `^[^:]*:` does this:

1. `^` anchors the regex to the start of the string. no matches in the middle of the string can occur.
2. `[^:]*` matches everything except colons, greedily, so it runs right to the first colon
3. `:` can match easily, because the next character happens to be a colon. Done.

No backtracking involved, this means it is also more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `.*?:` with the `Replace` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) :

```
string time = "Job started: donderdag 6 mei 2010 at 20:00:02"
var filterReg = new Regex(@".*?:", RegexOptions.Compiled);
filterReg.Replace(time, String.Empty, 1);
```